# find a group with the property :

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

a)find a nontrivial  group $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $G \times G $

what i'm sure is that $G$ must be infinite ! but have now idea how to get or construct such group 
i chose many $G$'s but all of the homomorphism was not injective

b) an infinite group in which every element has finite order but for each positive integer n there is an element of order n

the group  $G = (Z_1 \times Z_2 \times Z_3 \times Z_4 \times ...) $ satisfies the conditions except the one which says that every element have finite order .

how can we use this group to reach the asked group ?

Comment: Hint for 1: Consider an infinite number of copies of the same group. Hint for 2: Remember those restricted direct products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice question!

You've got some answers for $(b)$. With respect to answering $(a)$, (which is, indeed, a challenging question):

I think you'll find the following post from **[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43805/when-is-g-isomorphic-to-g-times-g)** very handy:

> Is there a finitely generated nontrivial group $G$ such that $G\cong G\times G$?

It was asked by Martin Brandenburg, and there are two excellent answers (in the affirmative) given there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for b: Consider a quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think for b you can consider $G=\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ where $p$ is a prime as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, you can use the subgroup of  $\mathbb{Z}_1\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_n \times \cdot$ consisting of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ such that  all but finitely many of the $a_i$ are $0$.

Comment: This subgroup is the direct sum of the $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and is often denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \ldots$